# D flip-flop sequencer to light three LEDs up sequentially together and then turn them all off

Tags: flipflop, sequential-logic

[image: D Flip-flop sequencer]

This circuit should turn on three lights sequentially whenever there is a high logic level until all are lit and then turn them all off, restarting the cycle.

It seems the following sequencing circuit has a design flaw or I am missing any important concept here (I know D latches change their levels whenever if the D level changes and there is a low-to-high transition at their input)

But... if letter R is lit (Q1 is high), then the output of the NOR gate (logic level for B) would be always zero, thus, making impossible of both B and R be lite together.

This was the official answer to the problem:

[image: Answer of the problem]

many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is this for a bra shop?

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the mature and professional contribution to the question.

Comment: @Transistor Always a question of why those letters were chosen

Comment: Maybe the NOR gate is supposed to really be an OR gate.  Seems like that would work at first glance but I haven't checked it.

Comment: @JohnD yes, that is exactly it! An OR gate in the place of the NOR gate fixes it, I just confirmed redoing the truth tables.

Comment: @Transistor I laughed :D

Comment: @laptop2d I'm guessing it's from the three-letter code for the country Brazil (population ~209,000,000).